# Bootstrapping to Judge the Fit of a Sampled Return Distribution

Tags: returns, statistics, simulations, distribution, bootstrapping

Consider the following: I have sampled yearly stock returns from a specified distribution.

What I want to do is compare how well my sampled distribution fits the empirical distribution of yearly returns. I am not interested in doing goodness of fit tests (e.g. Kolmogorov Smirnov test). Rather, I am interested in comparing the central moments of the sampled and the empirical distribution, say the first 4. However, I only have 30 observations of empirical annual returns, so I cannot have high confidence in my estimates.

Hence, I would like to increase my confidence, and to me it seems like bootstrapping would be a smart way to do this. However, since there is serial correlation in stock returns I cannot apply standard bootstrapping, as it would remove the serial correlation in the data. I have been looking at different types of Block bootstrapping, for example non-overlapping Block, Moving Block and Stationary Block. However, I find it hard to decide on which of the methods is most appropriate for the comparison I want to make.

Obviously, I am not looking for a perfect solution, but I am looking for an acceptable amount of accuracy, with a relatively low degree of complexity. I also emphasize that I am interested in estimating the parameters for the **yearly** return distribution. Are there any of the above Block bootstrapping techniques which are most appropriate for my usage, and if so, why?

My issue is a bit similar to this post: [Empirical distribution function of overlapping time series data](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17441/empirical-distribution-function-of-overlapping-time-series-data)

However, I did manage to come to any conclusion by investigating the sources which were referred to in the post above. Hence, I wonder if anyone with more experience regarding bootstrapping methods could shed some light on the above.