# Modelling approaches for interest rate risk in the banking book (IRRBB)

Tags: value-at-risk, banking-regulations, market-risk

I am having a hard time researching papers that deal with the measurement of market risk in the banking book. The trading book as I see it is similar to asset management and as the name says the trading desk view and therefore relatively well covered.

But what are useful quant/math/statistical approaches to estimate the VaR in the setting of the banking book?

There are various details that distinguish it from the usual portfolio view:

1. we deal with assets and liabilities and usually gap and basis risk
2. Often we deal with a one year view and people tend to use overlapping data in order to have a bigger sample size but sacrifying the iid property with all the problems that come with it (discussed [here on QSE](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/17441/empirical-distribution-function-of-overlapping-time-series-data) and on [linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/groups/3825142/3825142-6321252467589865473))

Earnings-based and credit-spread risk measurement are other topics in the context but are less in the scope of my question.

Thus I would really like to gather best practice research and papers here that cover this particular field of quantitative risk measurement.